# How can I automatically identify certain boxes in the \tracingoutput log?

Tags: logging

I have a program that is automatically generating a tex file describing a document. I want to be able to record the position and page number where a few boxes were ultimately laid out.

Is there any simple way to match up parts of the document with the matching part of the log file created by `\tracingoutput`? For example, is it possible to name boxes somehow and have those names show up in the log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you want `\tracingall`, You can be more specific in what you put out, eg

```
\documentclass{article}
\loggingoutput\scrollmode
\begin{document}

\sbox0{\parbox{2cm}{on two three four five six\[a=2\]seven}}

\typeout{my first box looks like this:}
\showbox0 \usebox0

\sbox0{\parbox{4cm}{on two three four five six\[a=2\]seven}}

\typeout{my second box looks like this:}
\showbox0 \usebox0

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
my first box looks like this:
> \box0=
\hbox(33.97223+28.97221)x56.9055
.\mathon
.\vbox(33.97223+28.97221)x56.9055
..\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x56.9055, glue set 0.5633
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
```

and

```
my second box looks like this:
> \box0=
\hbox(27.97223+22.97221)x113.81102
.\mathon
.\vbox(27.97223+22.97221)x113.81102
..\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x113.81102, glue set 4.2553fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
```

Comment: Ahh, cool. Thanks. I am not sure at all. I have used it a lot for writing papers, but have never attempted this kind of stuff. (I will accept in a couple of hours in case anyone else has suggestions, but it seems this should work nicely.)